# How can I success to download(with "fetch") the real world datasets of scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, download, sha256

I'm a beginner of Scikit-learn. If I run the code for download "the 20 newsgroups text dataset" of sklearn.datasets (The code is shown at https://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/real_world.html)

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
newsgroups_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train')
```

the following error is returned.

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-ade32d7dd81b> in <module>
      1 from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
----> 2 newsgroups_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     61             extra_args = len(args) - len(all_args)
     62             if extra_args <= 0:
---> 63                 return f(*args, **kwargs)
     64 
     65             # extra_args > 0

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\_twenty_newsgroups.py in fetch_20newsgroups(data_home, subset, categories, shuffle, random_state, remove, download_if_missing, return_X_y)
    257             logger.info("Downloading 20news dataset. "
    258                         "This may take a few minutes.")
--> 259             cache = _download_20newsgroups(target_dir=twenty_home,
    260                                            cache_path=cache_path)
    261         else:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\_twenty_newsgroups.py in _download_20newsgroups(target_dir, cache_path)
     73 
     74     logger.info("Downloading dataset from %s (14 MB)", ARCHIVE.url)
---> 75     archive_path = _fetch_remote(ARCHIVE, dirname=target_dir)
     76 
     77     logger.debug("Decompressing %s", archive_path)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\_base.py in _fetch_remote(remote, dirname)
   1195     checksum = _sha256(file_path)
   1196 
-> 1197     if remote.checksum != checksum:
   1198         raise IOError("{} has an SHA256 checksum ({}) "
   1199                       "differing from expected ({}), "

OSError: C:\Users\owner\scikit_learn_data\20news_home\20news-bydate.tar.gz has an SHA256 checksum (cb5c6e663e59b628d9016d3cb2a3992ad38811d846c04561c3fbfa58badcb1f7) differing from expected (8f1b2514ca22a5ade8fbb9cfa5727df95fa587f4c87b786e15c759fa66d95610), file may be corrupted.
```

The downloaded file size (C:\Users\owner\scikit_learn_data\20news_home\20news-bydate.tar.gz) is 1KB. However the real size of the file is about 14MB ([http://qwone.com/~jason/20Newsgroups/](http://qwone.com/%7Ejason/20Newsgroups/)).

Why fetch(downloading) does failed and how can I success downloading the file with 'fetch_20newsgroups'?

My OS is Windows10

Many thanks.

Comment: You should try to update your scikit-learn version to be sure that your are pointing to the last reference of the dataset. If this do not work, you can still download it manually.

Comment: It seems you failed to download the file.  First, check your sklearn version (because the URL may have changed).  Second, in the current sklearn version, the download link is here: https://ndownloader.figshare.com/files/5975967.  Check if you can download the file if you copy & paste the URL to the browser.  If this link is suspicious, check the source code here (https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/2beed55847ee70d363bdbfe14ee4401438fba057/sklearn/datasets/_twenty_newsgroups.py#L55-L59).

Comment: Third, the sklearn code simply use urlretrieve function to download the file.  Try `from urllib.requests improt urlretrieve; urlretrieve(url, filename)` to see if the function is working.  Finally, there is a chance that you do not have a write permission to the desired file path (but very unlikely if you could create a 1KB file already).

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason. The reason is that our company blocked amazon website for the reason of security. so the downloading is failed. The 20 newsgroups text dataset maybe saved in amazon and scikit-learn module takes the data from it. Message from our company shows that 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pfigshare-u-files' and 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/' are blocked.

Thanks to **Kota Mori**. Your answer gives me some hint. The URL is 'https://ndownloader.figshare.com/files/5975967' and if I copy it to web-browser, the address is changed to 'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pfigshare-u-files/5975967/20newsbydate.tar.gz?...' and blocked image shows up.

Comment: Googling `20news-bydate.tar.gz` seems to show several places where this file may be downloaded.  Maybe one isn't blocked for you.